# size of the character string str initialized as char str[]="S\032ABCD"

Tags: c

Size of the character string `str` initialized as `char str[]="S\032ABCD"`

What really does this null character mean to the result of the `sizeof` operator?

Comment: That isn't a null-character, it's the escape sequence `\032`.

Answer (score 2):

The size of a string literal is the number of characters plus 1 for the terminating NUL byte. In your case `sizeof "S\032ABCD"` is 7 (because \032 is an octal escape sequence and represents a single character). Since this literal is used as an array initializer of a character array, `sizeof str` is 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

In C, any number with with a leading `0` is considered as octal. Hence, the `032` as a whole is considered as the single character. So the `sizeof` is 7 (6 characters + 1 for nul-termination).

If you just remove the octal escape `\` then you'll get the sizeof as 8.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size of  in bytes, determined by its type.

This is not to be confused with `strlen` which measures the length of a string in characters and looks for a NUL terminator.

`sizeof` cares not for your NULL terminator, it doesn't look at your array and think "actually, this is probably a string, therefore I'll looks for the NUL terminator."  Furthermore it could not possibly do this in the general case as `sizeof` does its thing at compile time.

Comment: It's `NUL`, not `NULL`. One is an ASCII name, the other the identifier of a macro expanding to a null pointer constant.

Comment: @Jens: Good catch, I shouldn't have used all caps :D.  Thanks.